# Coldfusion Builder Snippets repository

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

I'm looking for Coldfusion Builder snippets repository. I tried looking in github but didn't find any useful snippets.

[https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=coldfusion+snippets&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=coldfusion%20snippets&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)

Anybody knows snippets repository where I can import in my coldfusion builder?

Comment: That's a great question. I build my own repo, but it would be cool to have one that everyone could use and update.

Comment: Coldfusion Builder 2 have default Snippets and gone in CF builder 3?

Answer (score 0):

@Vlad, a google search found the git repository if Snippets compatible with ColdFusion Builder at

https://github.com/cfeclipse/cfeclipse/wiki/Code-Snippets

To install,

- copy the zip from Git to a local folder,
- open cfbuilder preferences and enter "snippets" in the search box.
- Note the path displayed for ColdFusion Snippets.
- Open the downloaded zip file and extract to that same folder.

The downloaded snippets will now show up in the snippets view of CFBuilder.

I have tested this in Coldfusion Builder 2 and 3.